# Remove schema instance from JAXB schema location

Tags: xml, jaxb

Come to here to ask for litle help if someone know work with Jaxb technology. I want achieve generate XML with Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION and this create something like this

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="Document.xsd"

and i want omit this  **xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd"** element,
so far i didnt find any solution, and also  nowhere wasnt mentioned any similar situation how can it be edited this generated tag. is here someone to know any steps how can it be done? thanks a lot for help.

Cheers

Comment: Your question confuses me.  You say that you add schemaLocation using the appropriate `Marshaller` property and then you ask how to remove it.  What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, marshaller with jaxb_schema_location generate me full schema like above but what i want is remove ** xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd"** element from it,so far i didnt find any way do it to required state,thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to set the `Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION` property is to have it appear in the XML that is marshalled.  If you do not want it to appear then you need to not set that property.

---

## UPDATE

> because i have some specification where that property
>   xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd" cannot be shown so final tag must
>   look like ; so far without any
>   success

Based on this comment, I believe you are looking for information on how to namespace qualify your model.  Below is an example.

### Java Model

**package-info**

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="xsi", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    }
)
package forum20397718;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Document**

```java
package forum20397718;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Document")
public class Document {

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```java
package forum20397718;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);

        Document document = new Document();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(document, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: hi, yes understand, but i have litle specific case,when i need it without  **xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd"** attribute,and this i cant achieve.

Comment: @user3069432 - If you don't want it written then why are you setting the property?

Comment: because i have some specification where that property  xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd" cannot be shown so final tag must look like **<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">** so far without any success

Comment: @user3069432 - I have updated my answer with some information that may be helpful.

Comment: Hi,thank you,seems to me good solution, but also i thinking about that property **xsi:schemaLocation= "Document.xsd"** can be just remove from root tag some methods from org.w3c.dom? i found etc. **removeAttributeNS(String arg0, String arg1)** from Element class but dont know what parameters i can fill inside that method.